# How can I check if a Django form saved to show appropriate feedback?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, save, message

I'm using `Django 1.8`.I'd like to do something like this in a view:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Changes saved!')
```

But if the `save()` fails, it will still show a success message. How can I confirm that the save was actually successful?

I think I could put the message in `post_save`, but the content of the message itself depends on the view the `ModelForm` is used in, not the `Model` itself.

Thanks!

Comment: How could the form save fail, but no exception be raised?

Answer (score 4):

There's probably a neater way but you could wrap it in a `Try/Except` block:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
    try:
       form.save()
    except:
       # raise exception or error message

    messages.success(request, 'Changes saved!')
```

This is also inelegant, but you could add a [post_save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-save) hook. If `created=True` then it must have saved.

However, if your form is valid, it should be unlikely that it did not save (unless you have a transaction error in your database)

Answer (score 2):

If the `.save()` method fails, Django should raise an exception. You should not worry about it. But, if you still want to be sure, you can try to perform a filter and see if the object was created or not.

```
if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    try:
        my_object = MyModel.objects.get(**form.cleaned_data) # retrieve the created object
        messages.success(request, 'Changes saved!')
    except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
        # Create error message for object not created
    except:
        # Create message for other exceptions
```

(This checking is not recommended though as it will lead to an additional database hit. )